# Linear Regression When X and Y are Intertwined

Tags: regression

In Harvey Motulsky's book *Intuitive Biostatistics* (4th edition, page 339) he discusses a common mistake in linear regression referred to as "fitting data when x and y are intertwined". This is the case where a predictor variable is a function of the response variable, which potentially creates false relationships between x and y. I have looked in about 10 books on linear regression and have not found any discussion of this problem. Does it go by another name or is covered by one of the assumptions intrinsic to linear regression?

Comment: It is indirectly covered by the standard assumption that $x$ is measured without appreciable error: if $x$ truly is computed as a function of $y,$ then because $y$ has an assumed error, so would $x,$ which is problematic.  There is no inherent mathematical or statistical reason why linear regression would be invalid *just because* an explanatory variable is conceptualized as a function of the response variable. Thus, much seems to ride on exactly what "is a function of" is intended to mean.  Perhaps you can glean this from the context in the book.

Comment: I don't have this book. Offhandedly, it seems misleading. Isn't the "intertwinement" of $X$ and $Y$ what we fundamentally model with regression? A formal definition would be nice. It sounds like your understanding of this "intertwinement" is in the case of a causal diagram making a cyclic graph, or a graph that would be cyclic if $X$ caused $Y$. I've never heard this described as "intertwinement". I have heard the term "reverse causality" as a catchall for cases such as confounding by indication, the stuff that you can kind of suss out in longitudinal analyses with M-estimation.

Comment: The example Motulsky gives in that section I think goes some way to making his intent clearer: regressing change in blood pressure across an intervention (after minus before)  on blood pressure before. The appearance of the "before" measure in both X and Y induces a relationship even though the intervention actually had no effect.